# Escape Multiple Special Characters and Line Breaks in R

Tags: html, r, regex

I need to read in and then escape a section of HTML. Due to limitations at my work, I must do this in R.

My character string looks like the following:

````
"<div>good data</div>\n <p> glad you are here</p> \n 
<div> also good data </div>
\n\n```\n## [1] \"test2\"\n```\n\n\```\n## [1] \"test2\"\n```\n
<div> good as well </div>"
````

Ideally, after the regex, it would just say:

```
"<div>good data</div>\n <p> glad you are here</p> \n 
<div> also good data </div>\n
<div> good as well </div>"
```

I have tried:

````
gsub('\n\n```\n\\#\\# \\[1\\]', "", nameofstring)
````

But after adding the next character things get messed up!

Any help is appreciated thanks!!

Comment: trying delete all but div to /div, yes ?

Comment: Really I am just trying to delete "\```\n## [1] \"test2\"\n\```"  but am having trouble escaping the characters. I am a bit of a regex noob so sorry if its an easy solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can extract everything between `<div>` and `</div>` and collapse them in one string.

````
library(stringr)
string <- "<div> this is </div>\n\n```\n## [1] \"test2\"\n```\n\n\```\n## [1] \"test2\"\n```\n<div> so hard </div>"

str_c(str_extract_all(string, '<div>.*</div>')[[1]], collapse = '\n')
#[1] "<div> this is </div>\n<div> so hard </div>"
````

Comment: Apologies, I needed to further refine my question. I am trying to remove some plain text from an HTML file that is generated through markdown. I cant figure out how to hide it with CSS so I am removing it from the source. I have a lot of valid code between other divs so I cant get rid of it that way

Comment: @cbaylor Can you specify clear rules with examples about which text should be kept and which should be removed?

Comment: Hi Ronak, I was trying to remove an error message that was being inserted via Xaringan. I was able to fix my issue using literals. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
gsub('\n`+.*`+\n', ' ', nameofstring)
#[1] "<div> this is </div>\n <div> so hard </div>"
```

Or

```
gsub('\n`+[^`]+`+\n', ' ', nameofstring)
```

Comment: Apologies, I needed to further refine my question. I am trying to remove some plain text from an HTML file that is generated through markdown. I cant figure out how to hide it with CSS so I am removing it from the source. I have a lot of valid code between \n so I cant get rid of it that way.